# Multiple plots generated based on user selection - No handler registered

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a large app and am trying to put in interaction plots based on what the user selects. The MRE below simulates the part I am having problems with.

I am getting the following error if I select cyl:gear:

Error in (function (name, val, shinysession)  :
No handler registered for type .clientdata_output_plot_cyl:gear_width

Similar errors occur with the other selections.

I think that means that the list containers created in output$ems_interactions don't correspond with the ones requested by the oberveEvent and generated via the function gen_two-way_int_plots(), but I don't see how that is.

What I am trying to do is have all the selected plots display.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Multiple Plots with Shiny and ggplot2"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "ems_int_selected",label = "Select Interactions",choices = c("cyl:gear","cyl:carb","carb:gear"),multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      # Plots will be rendered here
      uiOutput("ems_interactions")
    )
  )
)


# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {  
  
  gen_twoway_int_plots<-function(fact_a,fact_b){#function to generate one interaction plot
    data<-mtcars #can be anything, mtcars for example
    data_col<-4 #hp for example, selected by user in app
    req(data,fact_a,fact_b,data_col)
    
    ggplot(data, aes(x = !!sym(fact_a),
                     y = !!sym(names(data)[data_col]),
                     color = factor(!!sym(fact_b)),
                     linetype = factor(!!sym(fact_b)),
                     shape=factor(!!sym(fact_b)))
    ) +
      stat_summary(fun = mean,geom="line",linewidth=1.5)+
      stat_summary(fun = mean,geom="point",size=4)+
      ggtitle(paste0("Interaction ",fact_a,":",fact_b))+
      guides(shape="none",linetype="none")
  }
  
  output$ems_interactions<-renderUI({#set up multiple two-way interaction plots based on user input
    data<-mtcars #can be anything, mtcars for example
    data_col<-4 #hp for example, selected by user in app
    int_selected<-input$ems_int_selected #user selected interactions, can be more than one
    req(data,data_col,int_selected)
    
    plot_list<-lapply(int_selected,function(i){
      plotOutput(outputId = paste0("plot_",i))
    })
    do.call(tagList,plot_list)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$ems_int_selected,{#generate the two-way interaction plots, must run after ems_interactions
    int_selected<-input$ems_int_selected #user selected interactions
    req(int_selected)
    
    for (i in int_selected){
      factors<-str_split_1(i,pattern = ":") #split the interaction into the two factors
      output[[paste0("plot_",i)]]<-renderPlot({ #render the plot for each selected interaction
        gen_twoway_int_plots(fact_a = factors[1],fact_b = factors[2])
      })
    }
    
  },ignoreInit = TRUE,ignoreNULL = TRUE)

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have two issues.  First, the function needs some update.  Second, your `i` refers to `cyl:gear` (as first choice) and as such you are defining `output$plot_cyl:gear` which is giving the error.  Once you address that, it works fine.  Try this

```
gen_twoway_int_plots<-function(fact_a,fact_b){#function to generate one interaction plot
  data<-mtcars #can be anything, mtcars for example
  data_col<-4 #hp for example, selected by user in app
  req(data,fact_a,fact_b,data_col)
  y = names(data)[data_col]
  ggplot(data, aes(x = .data[[fact_a]],
                   y = .data[[y]],
                   color = factor(.data[[fact_b]]),
                   linetype = factor(.data[[fact_b]]),
                   shape=factor(.data[[fact_b]] ) )
  ) +
    stat_summary(fun = mean,geom="line",linewidth=1.5)+
    stat_summary(fun = mean,geom="point",size=4)+
    ggtitle(paste0("Interaction ",fact_a,":",fact_b))+
    guides(shape="none",linetype="none")
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Multiple Plots with Shiny and ggplot2"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "ems_int_selected",label = "Select Interactions",choices = c("cyl:gear","cyl:carb","carb:gear"),multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      # Plots will be rendered here
      uiOutput("ems_interactions")
    )
  )
)


# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {  
  
  observe({print(input$ems_int_selected)})
  observeEvent(input$ems_int_selected,{#generate the two-way interaction plots, must run after ems_interactions
    int_selected<-input$ems_int_selected #user selected interactions
    req(int_selected)
    n = length(int_selected)
    
    lapply(int_selected, function(par) {

      for (j in 1:n){
        if (par == int_selected[j]) i = j
      }
    #for (i in int_selected){
      factors<-str_split_1(par,pattern = ":") #split the interaction into the two factors
      output[[paste0("plot_",i)]]<-renderPlot({ #render the plot for each selected interaction
        gen_twoway_int_plots(fact_a = factors[1],fact_b = factors[2])
      })
    #}
    })
  },ignoreInit = TRUE,ignoreNULL = TRUE)
  
  
  output$ems_interactions<-renderUI({#set up multiple two-way interaction plots based on user input
    data<-mtcars #can be anything, mtcars for example
    data_col<-4 #hp for example, selected by user in app
    int_selected<-input$ems_int_selected #user selected interactions, can be more than one
    req(data,data_col,int_selected)
    
    if (!is.null(input$ems_int_selected)) { 
      plot_list<-lapply(1:length(int_selected), function(i){
        plotOutput(outputId = paste0("plot_",i))
      })
      do.call(tagList,plot_list)
    }
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: that is perfect. I thought the colons might be causing a problem but I did not check the list names. Thanks!